# Steam won't run

Tags: dependencies, steam

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 indicator-network : Depends: unity8 (>= 7.82) but it is not going to be installed
 libcheese-gtk23 : Depends: libcheese7 (>= 3.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libclutter-1.0-0 (>= 1.13.2) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 (>= 0.91.8) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libcogl15 (>= 1.15.8) but it is not going to be installed
 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 : Depends: libglapi-mesa:i386 (= 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.5)
 libqt5gui5 : Depends: libegl1-mesa (>= 7.8.1) or
                       libegl1-x11
              Depends: libgbm1 (>= 8.1~0) but it is not going to be installed
 libubuntu-application-api-mirserver1 : Depends: libmirserver18 (>= 0.1.8+14.04.20140408.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libunity-mir1 : Depends: libmirserver18 (>= 0.1.8+14.04.20140411) but it is not going to be installed
 qtdeclarative5-qtquick2-plugin : Depends: libgl1-mesa-dri
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Every time I try and run Steam I get this error message, what should I do?

Comment: To help make it easier to help you, would you know what version of Ubuntu you are using? Specifically, could you open a terminal and type "lsb_release -a" and paste the results in your question above? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Steam is only available in the repositories as i386 (32-bit). Try again after:

`sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`

`sudo apt update`

Answer (score 0):

Download steam from steam.com and install it.

This might get steam up and running but it won't resolve your unmet dependencies error.

```
indicator-network libcheese-gtk23 libqt5gui5 libubuntu-application-api-mirserver1 libunity-mir1 qtdeclarative5-qtquick2-plugin
```

Download steam by running this command in terminal :

```
wget http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/archive/precise/steam_latest.deb
```

Then install steam by running this command :

```
sudo dpkg -i steam_latest.deb
```

If you get any errors when running this command:

```
sudo dpkg -i steam_latest.deb
```

edit your post with the output.